# Executing .R file in C# using R.net in visual studio

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio-2010

I have a .r file which fetches data from database, performs some calculation and write back to a new table in database.

I am trying to execute the .r file from C# using visual studio 2010.

The C# code is mentioned below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;
using RDotNet.Devices;
using RDotNet.Internals;


namespace EmbeddAssembly
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string rhome = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("R_HOME");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rhome))
                rhome = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1";

            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("R_HOME", rhome);
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + rhome + @"binx64");

            // Set the folder in which R.dll locates.
            //REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:Program FilesRR-2.12.0bini386″);
            REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin\x64");

           // REngine e = REngine.CreateInstance("test", new[] { "" });
            using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" }))  // quiet mode
            {

                foreach (string path in engine.EagerEvaluate(".libPaths()").AsCharacter())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(path);
                }
                engine.Evaluate(".libPaths(C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.1\\library)");
                engine.Evaluate("source(C:\\Users\\..\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\EmbeddAssembly\\multi.r)");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error but it is not calling the .r file.

The code in r file works fine because I am able to retrive data and write into the table. However on calling that from C# it is not performing any action.

Comment: Can someone kindly update?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing character delimitors around arguments to the R functions called. Also, avoid using backslashes when passing strings to R.NET's `Evaluate`. You may need to end up having quadruple backslashes (or even more if using regular expressions) to get things to work.

You should use something like:

```
engine.Evaluate(".libPaths('C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library')");
engine.Evaluate("source('C:/Users/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/EmbeddAssembly/multi.r')");
```

It seems you are using a very old version of R.NET; I strongly advise you to use [R.NET.Community on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community). I know there is an R.NET nuget feed still up too, but this appears not maintained anymore. Also, FYI, R.NET latest reference documentation is now [on a GitHub page](http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet)

Comment: Removed Quadruple backlashes from Evaluate and installed R.Net.Community. However I am getting this 3 Errors: error. 'RDotNet.REngine' does not contain a definition for 'SetDllDirectory', 'RDotNet.REngine' does not contain a definition for 'CreateInstance' and 'RDotNet.REngine' does not contain a definition for 'EagerEvaluate' and no extension method 'EagerEvaluate' accepting a first argument of type 'RDotNet.REngine' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you also specify where exactly I am missing Character delimitors to the R function called?

Comment: The methods you report as missing have indeed been removed, so this is normal. Please read the documentation for using R.NET 1.6, for instance starting with [the first tutorial](http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_basic_types)

Comment: Can anyone give any more input?

Comment: On executing program.cs I am only getting C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library in console